# 16 showers , 6 toilets, 8 sinks and 6 urinals what size of water pipe should be for the supply?

Tags: water, water-pressure, hot-water

I have building with 16 showers , 6 toilets, 8 sinks and 6 urinals
what size of water pipe should be for the supply?

Comment: Commercial or residential? How many people may be expected to be using these facilities simultaneously?

Comment: If all fixtures can be turned on at the same time then you need a 4 inch supply pipe. This assumes a half inch supply to each individual fixture. This would let you turn on all hot and cold lines at the same time.

Comment: If you anticipate that only half of the fixtures will be in use at any given time then a 2.75 inch supply would be appropriate.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, you should be posting that as an answer and you should support it with reasoning or resources. Comments aren't the place for it.

Comment: @isherwood Done, hopefully the math is understandable :)

Comment: This sounds like a commercial occupancy -- have you checked the applicable building regulations? In particular, unless you have a separate fire main, you'll likely have a fire flow source (either a standpipe, sprinklers, or both) you'll need to account for

Comment: @monkeyzeus I support your theory bit faucets almost drop down to 3/8” lines from the 1/2” pipe and they have even smaller orifices so based on 1/2” I would agree but the actual sizes are smaller, I would support an an answer with this in mind.

Comment: @EdBeal I provided the tools that OP would need to make the calculations. Unless OP can confirm the reductions then I'd be wasting my time. At my work the sinks flow at a full half inch of volume and the toilets are plumbed with a 1 inch line for a power-flush. I gave OP a fish and taught them how to fish in case they don't like the one I gave them :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about commercial or multi residential plumbing.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., water supply requirements are calculated using a table of **water supply fixture units** (wsfu) in the plumbing codes.  Below, I use the values for a public/commercial installation (residential requirements are less but the OP's question appears to be a commercial setting):

| fixture | cold | hot | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 showers | 48 | 48 | 64 |
| 6 toilets - flush valve | 60 | 0 | 60 |
| 8 sinks | 12 | 12 | 16 |
| 6 urinals - 1" flush valve | 60 | 0 | 60 |
|  | 180 | 60 | 200 |

Notice the **total** values are not a sum of hot + cold; they are also from the WSFU table.

After determining all your WSFUs from all types of fixtures in the group, you need to know the minimum water pressure and maximum supply line length.  These values, and the required WSFUs, allow you to consult a second table giving you the minimum supply pipe & meter size.  In this case, a 2" supply should suffice.

This calculation should be performed for each branch of the plumbing system.

You should not invent your own method based on pipe diameter because the tables in the building codes already account for pressure drop due to length of the supply lines, and available supply pressure.

[image: WSFU fixture requirements table]
[image: WSFU supply table]